# I am trying to convert multiple metrics using methods and I'm stuck I dont know what to do next?

Tags: java

I have my code here it is a mess I know but I'm confused with my logic and need help trying to get this together. So any help is appreciated. I want the output to be this "

CONVERSION TOOL

1.Gallons to liters

2. Liters to gallons
3. Teaspoons to milliliters
4. Milliliters to teaspoons

Please select the type of conversion you would like to make: 1

Please enter the gallons: 5

The total liters is 18.925"

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ConversionProgram {

public static final double LT_TO_GAL = .274;   
public static final double GAL_TO_LT = 3.785;        
public static final double TSP_TO_ML = 4.9289;
public static final double ML_TO_TSP = .202;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int nInitLit = 0;                       
    int nInitGal = 0;                       
    int nTotalLit = 0;
    double dResult = 0;
    double dNumber1 = 0;
    double dNumber2 = 0;
    int nPrice = 0;
    double dTotalGal = 0.0;             
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

    System.out.println("CONVERSION TOOL: ");   
    System.out.println("1. Gallons to liters ");
    System.out.println("2. Liters to gallons");
    System.out.println("3. Teaspoons to milliliters");
    System.out.println("4. Milliliters to teaspoons");
    System.out.print("");

    System.out.print("Please select the type of conversion you would like to make: ");
        int nConversion = input.nextInt();

    if (nConversion == 1) {        
        System.out.print("Please enter the gallons: ");
        double dGal = input.nextDouble();

    }

        else if (nConversion == 2) {
            System.out.print("Please enter the total liters: ");               
            double dLit = input.nextDouble();
        }

        else if (nConversion == 3 ) {
            System.out.print("Please enter the total teaspoons ");
            double dTsp = input.nextDouble();           
        }

        else if (nConversion == 4 ) {
            System.out.print("Please enter the total milliliters ");
            double dMil = input.nextDouble();               
        }


} //end main method

public static double calculateGallonsToLiters(double dGal) {
    double dTotGal = 0;                  
    dTotGal = dGal * GAL_TO_LT;
        return dTotGal;
    } 



public static double calculateLitersToGallons(double dLit){

    double dTotLt = 0;              
    dTotLt = dLit * LT_TO_GAL;
        return dTotLt;
    } //end


public static double calculateTeaspoonsToMliters(double dMlit){

    double dTotMl = 0;              
    dTotMl = dMlit * TSP_TO_ML;
        return dTotMl;
    } //end


public static double calculateMlitersToTeaspoons(double dTsp){
    double dTotTsp = 0;             
    dTotTsp = dTsp * ML_TO_TSP;
        return dTotTsp;
    } //end


public static void printResult(int nOpt, int nResultOperation){
        System.out.println("The total gallons is : " + nResultOperation);

    }//end method printResult} //end class
```

Comment: And what is your current output?

Comment: "CONVERSION TOOL

1.Gallons to liters

Liters to gallons
Teaspoons to milliliters
Milliliters to teaspoons
Please select the type of conversion you would like to make: 1

Please enter the gallons: 5
" It gets this far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to call the conversion method as well.
Change

```
public static void printResult(int nOpt, int nResultOperation){
    System.out.println("The total gallons is : " + nResultOperation);
}
```

into

```
public static void printResult(String unit, double result){
   System.out.println("The total " + unit + " is : " + result);
}
```

and

```
if (nConversion == 1) {        
    System.out.print("Please enter the gallons: ");
    double dGal = input.nextDouble();
}
```

into

```
if (nConversion == 1) {        
    System.out.print("Please enter the gallons: ");
    double dGal = input.nextDouble();
    double litres = calculateGallonsToLiters(dGal);
    printResult("litres", litres);
}
```

Comment: That helped, Thanks. I need to have a method to print the result how would I use that in the code I have currently for each conversion?

Comment: @NicholasNPeck see changes

Comment: Thank you so much appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Beside the correct answer given by Aidin i want to suggest to use a switch statement instead of if/else and get rid of all variables which are not needed and unimportant to make the code readable:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ConversionProgram {

    public static final double LT_TO_GAL = .274;   
    public static final double GAL_TO_LT = 3.785;        
    public static final double TSP_TO_ML = 4.9289;
    public static final double ML_TO_TSP = .202;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

        System.out.println("CONVERSION TOOL: ");   
        System.out.println("1. Gallons to liters ");
        System.out.println("2. Liters to gallons");
        System.out.println("3. Teaspoons to milliliters");
        System.out.println("4. Milliliters to teaspoons");
        System.out.print("");

        System.out.print("Please select the type of conversion you would like to make: ");
        int nConversion = input.nextInt();

        switch (nConversion){
            case 1:
                System.out.print("Please enter the gallons: ");
                printResult("liters",calculateGallonsToLiters(input.nextDouble()));
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.print("Please enter the total liters: ");
                printResult("gallons",calculateLitersToGallons(input.nextDouble()));
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.print("Please enter the total teaspoons ");
                printResult("milliliters",calculateTeaspoonsToMliters(input.nextDouble()));
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.print("Please enter the total milliliters ");
                printResult("teaspoons",calculateTeaspoonsToMliters(input.nextDouble()));
                break; 
            default:
                System.out.println("Not a valid option!");       
        }   
    }

    public static double calculateGallonsToLiters(double dGal) {
       return dGal * GAL_TO_LT;
    } 

    public static double calculateLitersToGallons(double dLit){
        return dLit * LT_TO_GAL;
    } 

    public static double calculateTeaspoonsToMliters(double dMlit){
        return dMlit * TSP_TO_ML;
    }

    public static double calculateMlitersToTeaspoons(double dTsp){
        return dTsp * ML_TO_TSP;
    }

    public static void printResult(String nOpt, double nResultOperation){
        System.out.println("The total " + nOpt + " is : " + nResultOperation);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good alternative. However, it is good practice to always end the switch with a `default` case

Comment: Awesome Thanks guys!